# Reference stored values of a dictionary from another namespace

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, namespaces

I am storing terms into a somewhat complex (at least for me) dictionary of type:

```
Dictionary<string, Term>
```

Where "Term" is a class that I have defined with a List of "Occurrences", as shown in the code below.

```
 namespace SomeNameSpace
 {
    public class Occurence
    {
        public int docID { get; set; }
        public int termOcc { get; set; }
    }

    public class Term
    {
        public int numbOfDocuments { get; set; }
        public int lastDocAdd { get; set; }
        public int termCount { get; set; }

        public List<Occurence> docOccurances = new List<Occurence>();
    }

    public class TermDictionary
    {
        public Dictionary<string, Term> termOccurence = new Dictionary<string, Term>();
    }

    public static void SomeMethod()
    {
        TermDictionary TermDictionary = new TermDictionary();
 .
 .
 .
```

When the void function "SomeMethod" completes there is a return to the calling namespace, which is not "SomeNameSpace" but some other namespace.

I would like to use the stored values from the dictionary in the other namespace so that I may access the dictionary based on queries input from a user.

Is there a way to have the data from this dictionary persist so that I may access it from another namespace?  Or perhaps a way to pass the dictionary to the other namespace so that I may use it there?

Comment: I don't see what's stopping you from doing this.  How is `SomeMethod` "returning" the new object?  How is the code calling `SomeMethod` trying to use that object?  Where is the error?

Comment: I'm confused - what do you mean "return to the calling namespace"?  Your method doesn't return anything or set any class members (neither does your constructor).  What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: It is not [namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0d941h9d.aspx) that are calling methods but methods which belong to classes (which are in namespaces, but only in order to avoid class name clashes) are calling other methods and use returned values. Also, your method `SomeMethod` cannot be out of any class.

Comment: You have this method in a class right? You can use a static class to call your static method.

Comment: Sorry for any confusion, this method is being called from another method in another namespace.  There are a lot of things the method does, and does just fine.  I am actually printing the dictionary data to an output file, but after that happens I would like to access the values of the dictionary again from another namespace.  I have left out a lot of code as an attempt to simplify my question.

Comment: What you are describing is _fields_ or _properties_ both of which would have been covered in a good _Learning c# 101_ book or tutorial rather than posting a question of that nature on SO.  You seem to be confused with _namespaces_.  Good luck!

Comment: No @MickyDuncan, I think I am having greater difficulty constructing a well defined question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The namespace is less relevant here. The actual boundary you should be thinking about is the class boundary. How do I get information between my classes? Namespaces are just a logical way of tagging likeminded classes together.

That said returning the dictionary is a crude way of achieving what you want. But a problem here is that it's your internal state and another class can change it. So either send it on its merry way as a readonly dictionary or wrap it in a little service interface that simply exposes a lookup method to hide the internals - the dictionary itself in this case.

Comment: Sending it on it's merry way is the problem I am trying to solve.  How do I accomplish this?

Comment: If a class in another namespace is to use one of the classes above it needs to add a using directive with the namespace like this at the top of the file: using SomeNamespace;

Comment: Namespaces give the compiler some clue on where to look for the types used in the code.